# Unsure why Android has issues with certain Opus files

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm not 100% sure where to post this cause it's kind of a strange issue. I recently discovered the Opus format and converted all my songs to it, so they would fit on my phone. However a few cd's I've converted from MP3 to Opus are having a strange issue. I did have to rename all the files from .opus to .ogg so they could be read by media players, but what's odd is that some of the cd's I've converted seem to lose their information when I copy them over to my device (Nexus 6 running 7.1.1).

Like, all the tag information is gone and every media player that's able to see it says the song is 00:00 in time. Yet when I actually play the song, it works totally fine. I can't even edit the tag information in any apps because it just disappears. Is there any reason it would do this? I've tried re-converting the songs a few times but the same problem still happens.

Answer (score 0):

Alright well I figured out what seems to be the issue. Apparently if the file has a large size album art (from what I can tell, anything 1MB and over) causes the tags to be unreadable. I went and re-tagged the file with a smaller album art and now it works fine. Unsure why this causes an issue, but I'm glad to have figured it out.